# Rails + Globalize: validate presence of generated attribute fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

I have a `Department` model in which I have translated attributes using the Globalize gem: `:name` and `:permalink`.

`:permalink` is automatically generated based on the department's `:name`, using a `:before_validation` callback.

I want the name and the permalink to be mandatory, so I added validation on the translation class and not null constraints in the migration.

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name, :permalink, fallbacks_for_empty_translations: true
  globalize_accessors

  before_validation :set_permalink, on: :create

  validates_associated :translations
  translation_class.validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
  translation_class.validates :permalink, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  private

  def set_permalink
    I18n.available_locales.each do |l|
      I18n.with_locale(l) { self.permalink = name.to_url }
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateDepartment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :departments do |t|
      # other attributes

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    Department.create_translation_table! name: { type: :string, null: false }, permalink: { type: :string, null: false, index: { unique: true } }
  end

  def down
    Department.drop_translation_table!
    drop_table :departments
  end
end
```

But when I try to create a department, the validation fails:

```
irb(main):001:0> Department.create!(name_en: 'Tools', name_fr: 'Outils')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Department::Translation Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "department_translations" WHERE "department_translations"."permalink" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Department::Translation Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "department_translations" WHERE "department_translations"."permalink" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Department::Translation Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "department_translations" WHERE "department_translations"."permalink" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Department::Translation Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "department_translations" WHERE "department_translations"."permalink" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Translations permalink can't be blank, Translations is invalid
```

However, if I remove the validation and the not null constraint for the permalink, the department can be saved AND the permalink is present for all translations.

I don't understand why the validation is failing... How can I setup the validation and the automatic generation of the permalink so that they work together?

I'm using Rails 4.2.5 with Globalize 5.

Comment: Did you fix it?